# How to access the Mobile App Event Data Extension in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I am trying to find out the way to access the Data Extension created by Mobile App Entry Event through journey builder.

my goal is to use this DE to link in attribute group.

Comment: may I ask if you managed to implement this input source (Mobile App Event)? I am trying to implement it but the journey remains empty although there is activity registered.

Answer (score 0):

According to a colleague, the `attributes` sent alongside `custom events` can be seen in Journey Builder under "Journey Data".[image]

Comment: Hi Bill, Thank you for response.  But I want to use the data coming through Mobile app event  in the attribute group to link it with another table and take some decision based on that. Also if the criteria meets I need to send those users to Personalization Studio in realtime.

Comment: I've tried following ways to capture the data through Mobile App event but not successful , 1. Update contact Activity - For this we are not getting email or mobile number so we are unable to retrieve EventKey from journey. 2 Personalization activity, but it doesn't have the journey data option as it's there for decision split. 3. Through Ampscript to upsert it into other DE, but it could works only with email, sms, push activity when it's sent out from journey. But I don't want to send any comms through journey, I want to send user to Personalization Studio for further logic

Comment: Apologies. It could very well be that what you want to do is not possible. I'm going to leave my answer as where these properties live isn't obvious and this might be the clue someone else needs.